# Set read ahead automatically on restart for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

I have set the blkdev readahead (see command below), however on reboot it gets reset back to 256. How do I have it so that it is automatically set even after reboot or what is the best way to make this setting permanent? Please give specific detailed answer.

```
sudo blockdev --setra 2048 /dev/sdc1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the command you noted above to `/etc/rc.local`, and that will be run on each boot.